# My updater is failing to close my main program (C#)

Tags: c#

I have an updater, which is called via the main program once an update is detected (from a remote XML file), first it checks whether the process is open

```
if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("conkinator-bot.exe"))
{

    clsProcess.CloseMainWindow();
    return true;

}
```

(this gets run for every process until it finds it (foreach loop))

the updater then downloads the file:

```
client.DownloadFile(url, "Conkinator-Bot-new.exe");
```

and then it attempts to delete the current one and rename it:

```
File.Delete("Conkinator-Bot.exe");
File.Move("Conkinator-Bot-new.exe", "Conkinator-Bot.exe");
```

but the error that I get when this occurs is the following:

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path       'D:\Conkinator's Skype Tool\Conkinator-Bot.exe' is denied.

however the new version of the program DOES download.

Comment: Try running your update process as administrator

Comment: @Glubus When I do, most of the time it still doesn't work, sometimes it does.

Comment: Try to add a little delay before downloading the file, because maybe your process need a little amount of time to close himself

Comment: Just because the main window is closed doesn't mean the process is over. You need to wait for the process to exit after you close the main window.

Comment: Why don't you close the main program from inside the main program itself after launching the updater? A short information message and then close everything

Comment: You dont have any windows that might pop up with things like "are you sure you dont want to save this" ? etc

Comment: `Closing main window` maybe `!=` `Closing application`? If the process is still up, it will lock the file.

Comment: @BugFinder That is because in the code I have a dialog box saying "Update x.x.x.x available! Do you want to update?"

Comment: Then you need to close that in your code too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because the main window is closed doesn't mean the process is over. You need to wait for the process to exit after you close the main window:

```
clsProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Ideally, you'd use a timeout - there might be something preventing the window from closing, or the process might have a faulty exit mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot easier to close the main program from inside the main program itself.

```
  string msg = "To update the application we need to close it. Do you want to continue?";
  if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
  {
     ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
     psi.FileName = "YourUpdaterFile.exe";           
     psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
     // Assuming a lot here but to just show the options available....
     psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
     Process.Start(psi);
     Application.Exit();
  }
```